# How can I track a specific object from a video input using a model that detects multiple objects

Tags: yolov8

I am reaching out for assistance regarding a computer vision task I am working on, particularly related to drawing trajectories for detected objects in a cricket delivery video.

I am relatively new to computer vision and have been following documentation from Ultralytics on object tracking in videos. Specifically, I have a pre-trained model that can detect both the bowler (class name: 'bowlers') and the ball (class name: 'balls') from a cricket delivery video provided as input to the model.

Below is a snippet of the code I have been working on:

```
  import cv2
  import numpy as np
  from collections import defaultdict
  from ultralytics import YOLO
  from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

  # load model
  model = YOLO('path/to/model')

  # open video file
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path/to/video')
  while not cap.isOpened():
     cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path/to/video')
     cv2.waitKey(1000)
     print('Wait for the header')

     # Store the track history for balls
     track_history = defaultdict(lambda: [])

     # Load class names
     class_names = model.names
     print(class_names)

     # Loop through the video frames
     while cap.isOpened():
     # Read a frame from the video
     success, frame = cap.read()

    if success:
       # Run YOLOv8 tracking on the frame, persisting tracks between frames
       results = model.track(frame, persist=True)

       #Get the boxes and track IDs if results[0].boxes is not None
       if results[0].boxes.id is not None:
         boxes = results[0].boxes.xywh.cpu()
         track_ids = results[0].boxes.id.int().cpu().tolist()

         print("Boxes: ", boxes)

         # Visualize the results on the frame
         annotated_frame = results[0].plot()

         # Plot the tracks
         for box, track_id in zip(boxes, track_ids):
            print("Box: ", box)
            x, y, w, h = box
            track = track_history[track_id]
            track.append((float(x), float(y)))  # x, y center point
            if len(track) > 30:  # retain 90 tracks for 90 frames
                track.pop(0)

            # Draw the tracking lines
            points = np.hstack(track).astype(np.int32).reshape((-1, 1, 2))
            cv2.polylines(annotated_frame, [points], isClosed=False, color=(230, 230,  230), thickness=10)

        # Display the annotated frame
        cv2_imshow(annotated_frame)
else:
    # Break the loop if the end of the video is reached
    break

# Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
    break

# Release video capture object and close windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Currently, the code successfully draws trajectories for both the bowler and the ball. However, my objective is to draw trajectories specifically for the ball's positions on every frame of the video.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or modifications to the code that would enable me to achieve this goal. Specifically, I am looking for assistance in modifying the code to draw trajectories solely based on the ball positions.